# What to assert when testing void callout method?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a void method that does an http callout. I have the HttpMock working and the test gives me 100% coverage. However, I can't figure out what to assert. I'm getting dinged by Checkmarx on a couple similar test classes where I don't have anything to assert.

I could assert something obvious that has nothing to do with the method, but that's pretty pointless (other than fulfilling Checkmarx).

`System.assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never add meaningless assertions which cannot fail. First and foremost, you want to test that a callout was made:

```
Test.startTest();
    MyClass.doStuff();
    Integer callouts = Limits.getCallouts();
Test.stopTest();

system.assertEquals(1, callouts, 'A callout should be made');
```

If there are any other observable side effects, test those also. Are you sending emails? Saving records? Doing anything whatsoever with the response? Test how your application interacts with different response values. For example, if you send an email when you get a 400 response, you would add an assertion against `Limits.getEmailInvocations()`. For a 200 response you might query back for some records which should have been updated.

Comment: I agree with your philosophy on meaningless assertions. In response to your questions... no, nothing happens internally that I can test for. The method does an HttpPost to an external API, and that's it. It returns nothing, it changes nothing on the system. I'll be submitting this for AppExchange security review soon, so I'll see if I can get them to advise on having a test with no assertion.

Comment: Yeah, then just make sure a callout was made and you are done.

Comment: What about... could I add a line in the actual method (not the test) that says if Test.isTesting, save some meaningless record, and then I could system assert on that record? Would the record actually be inserted, or would it treat it like a test insert? (Either way, it's still pointless.)

Comment: I recommend against it. Testing against governor consumption is ample. If you wrap the callout in a `try`/`catch`, you may need a bit more depth to cover the `catch` block.

Comment: Thanks for that sample code on getCallouts(). That should do it.

Comment: I don't think the getCallouts works... during a test, it doesn't actually appear to call out.

Comment: It doesn't actually call out because you set a mock, but the `Limits` class should still increment the value. I'm fairly certain it has when I've run such tests.

Answer (score 2):

I found a good way to have System asserts in unit tests for void methods: @TestVisible variables. You add the variables in the class you want to test, right at the top before any methods. In the void method, you can set the variable -- for example, at the end where you would be inserting records, you set the variable equal to the list of records.

Then, in the unit test, just system assert on the variable. Works great, is meaningful code, and easy to do.